# Could a bad transformer be the cause of too low power getting to my doorbell chime?

Tags: transformer

I have a Nest Hello Doorbell, and it seems to be working.  However, when I connect it up to my electronic doorbell chime, I can't seem to access certain features of the chime (it has the ability to change the tune, volume, length of the mp3 to play).  I measure the voltage at the transformer and I get around 16.5V ***(This is prolly wrong.  The load must have been disconnected.  See edit below)***.  I measure the voltage at the doorbell and I get around 15.2V.  My question is, is that normal?  Could this be caused by a old transformer, or just bad wirers causing some resistance or something else?

## EDIT

So, I've replaced all of the wire and it still looks funny.

I'm getting around 16.5V without load, 15.5V *before* the load (i.e. at the transformer) when the load is attached.  Is this a transformer issue?

Comment: That's a symptom of wire resistance, nothing to do with the transformer.

Comment: Hmmm., that's what I thought..  I'll replace the wire.

Comment: I doubt it is bad wires, they do not change much however I believe you are on the correct path. Bad connections are more than likely your problem.

Comment: @Gil, yeah, I thought that too.  I tried to solder any of the joins, but it didn't help.  I'll explore it more when I can and report back.

Comment: Try putting your volt meter across sections of the circuit and see where you are losing the voltage.

Comment: Hi @Gil, I've updated the question with new information.

Comment: Hi @Hearth, I've updated the question.  Unsure if you get notified on a question edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "before the load"?

Comment: @Hearth, off of the transformer. I must have been mistaken before. That should be constant with or without a load, right? This sounds more akin to a bad battery.

Comment: No, transformer voltage will sag when a load is connected.

Comment: @Hearth, by around 1 Volt? Sounds excessive.

Comment: 1V is only about 6%.  Not a great amount in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: What causes a transformer's voltage to sag anyway?